# How to scrape data using Beautifulsoup that shows up after selecting an option from the select tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data about course IDs and times of classes from a college course-schedule website (https://internet3.trincoll.edu/ptools/courselisting.aspx). The website has dropdown menu making you select your major and shows you classes corresponding to the major you select. The dropdown menu content uses the  and  tag.

**How do I scrape class data of other majors when they all are in the same URL (the only change is in the selected="selected" on the major)?** [dropdown menu and the inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq2g9.jpg)

I tried changing the tags so that another major has the `selected = "selected"` tag but that did not work. Here is the code-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://internet3.trincoll.edu/ptools/courselisting.aspx').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')
not_selected = soup.find('option', selected = 'selected')
not_selected.extract()
selected = soup.find('option', value = 'CPSC')
selected["selected"] = 'selected'
print(soup)
```

While the output has CPSC as `selected = "selected` in the option tag (and the AMST option tag does not appear), the content of the webpage still shows the content of the default selected option (i.e. AMST).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the other pages you need to use their Ajax API:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://internet3.trincoll.edu/ptools/courselisting.aspx"

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    courses = [v["value"] for v in soup.select("#ddlList [value]")]

    for c in courses:
        data = {}
        for inp in soup.select("input[value][name]"):
            data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]

        data["ddlList"] = c
        data["ddlLevelList"] = "0"
        data["ddlTermList"] = "1241"  # <-- Fall 2023
        data["ddlSession"] = "0"
        data["__EVENTTARGET"] = "ddlList"
        data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
        data["__LASTFOCUS"] = ""

        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url, data=data).content, "html.parser")

        print(c)
        print("-" * 80)
        for id_, title in zip(soup.select(".TITLE_id"), soup.select(".TITLE_title")):
            print(f"{id_.text:<10} {title.text}")
        print()
```

Prints:

```
AMST                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3170       African-American History      
3191       Anthropology of Museums
3252       Born in Blood         
3182       Early American Women's Lit
3172       Abolition: A Global History  
3174       Sports and American Society
2355       Race and Urban Space
1416       Independent Study 
3175       Race, Gender, Global Security
3080       Black Women Writers 
1449       Teaching Assistantship
1542       Research Assistantship   
3359       Senior Thesis Part 1                                                                          
2745       Approaches to American Studies                                                                
3177       Race, Gender, Global Security                                                                 
3079       Black Women Writers                                                                           
1565       Museums and Communities Intern                                                                
1441       Independent Study             
1437       Research Project                                                                              
1438       Thesis Part I               
1440       Thesis Part II                                                                                
1439       Thesis       
3028       Urban Politics                                                                                
                                                    
ANTH                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1701       Intro to Cultural Anthropology                                                                
1797       Intro to Cultural Anthropology   
2398       Intro to Cultural Anthropology                                                                
2360       Intro to Political Ecology

...and so on.
```